# How to make rotated text look good with Java2D

Tags: text, rotation, render, java-2d

My question is not about how to rotate text with Java2D; I know how to do that.  What I don't know is how to make the rotated text "look good."  For example, if you create a text box in PowerPoint and rotate it, the text appears sharp and clear no matter the rotation angle.  However, text drawn with `g2D.drawString()` looks okay at 0 or 90 degrees but not so good at other angles.  Is there a way to manipulate the text to clean or sharpen it up?  If so, then if someone could point me to where look to learn how to do this I would be so thankful.

Below is a little program that illustrates what I'm talking about.  The bigger font isn't too bad when rotated but still doesn't look very professional.  The smaller font when rotated is terrible.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RotateTest extends JPanel {
    String message = "How does this text look?";

    public RotateTest() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 280));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                       RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2D.setFont(new Font("MyriadPro", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g2D.drawString(message, 80, 20);

        AffineTransform orig = g2D.getTransform();

        double angle = Math.toRadians(7.0);
        g2D.rotate(-angle, -10, 80);
        g2D.drawString(message, 80, 80);
        g2D.setTransform(orig);

        angle = Math.toRadians(30.0);
        g2D.rotate(-angle, -40, 80);
        g2D.drawString(message, 60, 260);
        g2D.setTransform(orig);

        g2D.setFont(new Font("MyriadPro", Font.BOLD, 12));
        g2D.drawString(message, 380, 20);

        angle = Math.toRadians(7.0);
        g2D.rotate(-angle, -10, 80);
        g2D.drawString(message, 380, 120);
        g2D.setTransform(orig);

        angle = Math.toRadians(30.0);
        g2D.rotate(-angle, -40, 80);
        g2D.drawString(message, 320, 400);
        g2D.setTransform(orig);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("RotateTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new RotateTest().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any code to show ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I once had a similar problem, and solved it by drawing the text with high precision to an image, then drawing the rotated image.

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

public class RotatedText extends JPanel {
    String message = "How does this text look?";

    public RotatedText() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 280));
    }

    public BufferedImage createStringImage(Graphics g, String s) {
        int w = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(s) + 5;
        int h = g.getFontMetrics().getHeight();

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D imageGraphics = image.createGraphics();
        imageGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        imageGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        imageGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        imageGraphics.setFont(g.getFont());
        imageGraphics.drawString(s, 0, h - g.getFontMetrics().getDescent());
        imageGraphics.dispose();

        return image;
    }

    private void drawString(Graphics g, String s, int tx, int ty, double theta, double rotx, double roty) {
        AffineTransform aff = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(theta, rotx, roty);
        aff.translate(tx, ty);

        Graphics2D g2D = ((Graphics2D) g);
        g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        g2D.drawImage(createStringImage(g, s), aff, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setFont(new Font("MyriadPro", Font.BOLD, 20));

        drawString(g, message, 80, 20, 0, 0, 0);
        drawString(g, message, 80, 80, -Math.toRadians(7.0), -10, 80);
        drawString(g, message, 60, 260, -Math.toRadians(30.0), -40, 80);

        g.setFont(new Font("MyriadPro", Font.BOLD, 12));

        drawString(g, message, 380, 20, 0, 0, 0);
        drawString(g, message, 380, 120, -Math.toRadians(7.0), -10, 80);
        drawString(g, message, 320, 400, -Math.toRadians(30.0), -40, 80);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("RotateTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new RotatedText().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got the time to test this but will the following code help?:

```
Graphics2D g2d; 
g2d.setRenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

This will only work on Graphics2D. If you're using normal Graphics you can cast your Graphics object to the 2D version like so:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; //if Graphics object name is g.
```

Let me know!
Good luck

Comment: Thanks Byron ... I tried that but the rotated text still doesn't look that great (see my sample code above).

Comment: I tried out your code and I see the problem you're having and to be honest I'm not sure why the text looks that bad but my gut feeling is that it has something to do with the font not being able to coop with the rotation

Comment: If you take a look at this site: http://www.subbu.org/javaapps/rotate/RotateTextDemo.html is your code as ugly in this example? (not my code + it isn't Graphics2D)

Comment: Hey Byron, thanks for the response.  Sorry I haven't answered; I've been away and been doing other stuff for the last couple weeks.  I think what'll I try to do is experiment with different fonts and see is any look better at different angles.

Comment: (I forgot all about this question until I happened to notice just today that I had a response--the one above)  I had been using Trebuchet MS, which didn't look too bad.  The approach above by sina72 works quite well.

Comment: Well I have tested applying RenderingHints that sina72 has used to configure my Graphics2D and it worked good even without creating an image. Well some letters are little jumping while changing rotation because it is not rendered as image but it does its job very well :)